# React/Redux Carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I am creating my own site for my resume and have run up against an issue I'm not exactly sure how to solve. I am using React and Redux, the issue comes up that what I want is to display small little projects in a carousel type format using react with proper redux integrated in. Currently my file structure looks like:
    `src/
       actions/
          index.js
       components/
          App.js
          NavBar.js
          Projects.js
          projects/
             Project1/
             Project2/
       containers/
          Main.js
       reducers/
          index.js
          projects.js`

I am not sure exactly how to accomplish what I want, I have searched for a good solution, but haven't really come across anything yet. I am still relatively new to react. What I don't want is to display one project, scroll down display the next, scroll some more... What I have tried is:

```js
let components = [{TicTacToe}, {}];
let index = 0;

export default class Projects extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      component: components[0]
    };
  }
  renderProject(i)
  {
    this.setState({component: components[i]});
  }

  backRotate()
  {
    index--;
    if(index < 0)
    {
      index = components.length - 1;
    }
    this.renderProject(index);
  }

  forwardRotate()
  {
    index++;
    if(index >= components.length)
    {
      index = 0;
    }
    this.renderProject(index);
  }

  render() {
    return(
    <div>
      <button onClick='backRotate'>Back</button>
      <div class='carousel-container'>
        <this.state.component />
      </div>
      <button onClick='forwardRotate'>Next</button>
    </div>
  ) }
}
```

I originally thought this would work, but it does break. I am currently running through App.js in my components folder adding the NavBar component and then adding the Main.js container. The reason for this container was the fact that I need a back and forward button to rotate through each project just like a carousel of images. I have considered adding all components and then just hiding and revealing, but this seems like a needless waste of resources and that there should be a better way to accomplish this.

Is there a way to replace a component on a button click? Completely remove the original component and add the new component in? If so, how do I also accomplish this using redux? Currently my projects reducer is just a place holder.

Comment: Did you try `let components = [TicTacToe, {}];`? Also: `onClick={this.backRotate}`

Comment: And `{this.state.component}`

Comment: See my answer below: do you need it to be animated? and some more question?, are the components already imported? will they be passed by props, or do you also need dynamic component loading?

Comment: Dynamic component loading would be cool, currently just importing at the top.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it breaks because the `components`array contains objects, and React can't have that.

A valid React element is either a node (HTMLElement, React Component, text or number) or an array of nodes.

If you just want to keep React components in a collection and be able to select which is displayed, first you have to remove the braces in the `components` array, like so:

```
let components = [TicTacToe, AnotherComponent];
```

And you will also need to fix your `backRotate`and `forwardRotate` handlers. They can't be string like in html (note the braces instead of quotes):

```
<button onClick={this.backRotate}>Back</button>
<button onClick={this.forwardRotate}>Next</button>
```

...and must be bound to your component instance. A way to bind them is to use the [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Function/bind) method. It should be done in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.backRotate = this.backRotate.bind(this);
    this.forwardRotate= this.forwardRotate.bind(this);
}
```

Without binding `this` would not be a reference to your component instance and calling this within the handlers would definitely fail.

`TicTacToe` and `AnotherComponent` must be classes extending `React.Component` or `React.PureComponent`, or must be pure functional components of props.

Also, its clearer and may be more supported to declare a capitalized variable containing the component:

```
render() {
    const Comp = this.state.component;
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.backRotate}>Back</button>
            <div class='carousel-container'>
                <Comp />
             </div>
             <button onClick={this.forwardRotate}>Next</button>
        </div>
     );
}
```

Finally, you should make `index` a state of your component (it's changed with the controls of the component) and `components` a prop (it does not change within the component).

Instead of setting the current component in state you will set the current component index:

```
import React from 'react':
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { TicTacToe, AnotherComponent } from 'path/to/named/imports/TicTacToeAndAnotherComponent';

export default class Projects extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        components: PropTypes.any,
    }
    static defaultProps = {
        components: [TicTacToe, AnotherComponent],
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            index: 0,
        };
        this.backRotate = this.backRotate.bind(this);
        this.forwardRotate= this.forwardRotate.bind(this);
    }
    backRotate() {
        const { components } = this.props;
        const { index } = this.state;
        if(index - 1 < 0) {
            this.setState(() => ({ index: components.length - 1 }));
        } else {
            this.setState(() => ({ index: index - 1 }));
        }
    }

    forwardRotate() {
        const { components } = this.props;
        const { index } = this.state;
        if(index >= components.length) {
            this.setState(() => ({ index: 0 }));
        } else {
            this.setState(() => ({ index: index + 1 }));
        }
    }
    render() {
        const Comp = this.props.components[this.state.index];
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.backRotate}>Back</button>
                <div class='carousel-container'>
                    <Comp />
                 </div>
                 <button onClick={this.forwardRotate}>Next</button>
             </div>
         );
    }
}
```

Either way Redux won't help you with that.

The purpose of Redux is mainly to provide a single source of data (single source of truth), provide actions and reducers to mutate this data, and notify components registered to listen to store updates. Weither you connect your carousel to the store or not isn't really relevant to resolve your iisue.

Comment: Perfect I appreciate that, it definitely works. I feel like for my code to be better maintainable it would be better for the components to be passed by props, or am I barking up the wrong tree so to speak? One of the big reasons to do this is so I'm better able to understand how everything is supposed to work together. Importing the components at the top does work, but when I add a second, a third, etc. projects into my list that creates that many more imports, right?

Comment: The way I set it, the components classes are actually meant to be passed as props, the defaultProps work but are just there for show. But weither you pass them from props or not, you will have to import them at some point (and also the compiler you use must do its magic before your bundle is actually made available to the browser). Look into import as a promise and lazy loading for dynamic imports

Comment: Also `import * as components from`... may help you.